# Display dialog not from activity

Tags: android

I'm working on a view at Android 3.0, and in that specific scenario I don't have an access to the activity.

I need to display a dialog on the screen but I cannot use `showDialog()` since I don't have access to the Activity methods. But I do have access to the context which might help.

Does anybody has an idea how to display a dialog without using the `showDialog()` method?
I need it also to be shown at a specific (x,y) point.

Comment: what is the particular situation? From where you need to show the dialog?

Comment: It's a service that displays a view. I need to display the dialog when the view is clicked.

Comment: Ok, where the view is located? Is it a widget?

Comment: No, it's not a widget.
It's displayed above an activity, I means that it hides some of an activity.

Comment: So what entity is it? Is it a dialog? Show the code, please.

Comment: It's a service, sorry but I can't get the specific code that would help you.

Comment: I'm very interested in showing UI from the service. How do you do it?

Comment: By WindowManager, I display a view on the screen where I need

Answer (score 1):

How about creating an `AlertDialog` passing that context in?

It shows you a standard modal message box ...

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html

Comment: Ah, didn't notice the bit about specific co-ordinates. Perhaps you could use `Toast` in that case ... http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

Comment: Toast isn't good enough, I need options also to be displayed in the dialog.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469005/show-alertdialog-in-any-position-of-the-screen should be able to address the coordinate requirement, in which case this answer is correct AFAICS.