# Dialog with transparent background in Android

Tags: android, android-dialog

How do I remove the black background from a dialog box in Android. The pic shows the problem.

[image]

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Screen1.this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.themechanger);
```

Comment: please show the code for the dialog creation

Comment: this situation also works in this two lines of codes here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186818/set-transparent-background-to-alertdialog-in-android/60867495#60867495

Comment: Find the best answer here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836938/remove-border-padding-from-dialog)

Answer (score 806, accepted):

Add this code

```
 dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Or this one instead:

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Comment: Thank you! However, I prefer to use `dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawableResource(R.color.transparent));`

Comment: this solution helps . issue is, the width will fit the screen. there will be no padding as compared to normal dialog. But Android 4.1 handles it by default

Comment: What about if i am using ALert Dialog ??

Comment: If you're inside a DialogFragment, just call getDialog().getWindow() ... (after the view was created, e.g. in your onViewCreated callback).

Comment: I prefer to use `dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.transparent);`

Comment: how to do it for popup?  I tried this popup.getContentView().setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent); but didn't work

Comment: This will change the padding of dialog. I believe the used background is 0 patch image. Is there any way not affecting the padding of dialog?

Comment: It will work but if u click that transparent area dialogue will not close  how to handle this?

Comment: `setBackgroundDrawable` is deprecated. It seems `setBackground(Drawable drawable)` is the new way of doing this

Comment: The hero we need, but not the one we deserve

Comment: In Kotlin, this can be written as `dialog.window!!.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))`

Answer (score 107):

**TL;DR;** You just need two things, **firstly** in your `style` do something like:

```xml
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

**Secondly,** make 100% sure said `style` gets applied to your dialog (maybe by passing to constructor).

### Full example

```
<style name="NewDialog">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Use in Java:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.NewDialog);
```

I hope helps you !

Comment: It will work but if u click that transparent area dialogue will not close  how to handle this?

Comment: @John You can use: dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

Comment: You can use parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog" to make exit on touch outside as default.

Comment: even possible to handle the alpha for dim background:  `<item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0.2</item>` or programmatically  `window.getAttributes().dimAmount = 0.2f;`

Answer (score 36):

I've faced the simpler problem and the solution i came up with was applying a transparent bachground THEME. Write these lines in your styles

```
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/blue_searchbuttonpopupbackground</item>
</style>
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

And then add

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
```

in your main manifest file , inside the block of the dialog activity.

Plus in your dialog activity XML set

```
 android:background= "#00000000"
```

Comment: Or use this if you just want to set the Dialog's style:
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">

Answer (score 20):

if you want destroy dark background of dialog , use this

```
dialog.getWindow().setDimAmount(0);
```

Comment: Thank you. It is what I have been looking for it. It's great.

Comment: This does the job in the most simple way, thank you! However, if you want your app to run on 100% of the devices out there (I have set minimum SDK version to 15), Android suggests the following:

`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(alertDialog.getWindow()).setDimAmount(0);
}`

Comment: I prefer using this. Very simple!

Comment: With just this, there will be no dimming but there will be shadow around your dialog

Answer (score 17):

Somehow Zacharias solution didn't work for me so I have used the below theme to resolve this issue...

```
<style name="DialogCustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
</style>
```

One can set this theme to dialog as below

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.DialogCustomTheme);
```

Enjoy!!

Comment: <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
This line should replace by below line or else you have to add a value of transparent in colors.xml file.
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>

Answer (score 13):

Dialog pop up fill default black background color or theme color so you need to set `TRANSPARENT` background into Dialog. Try below code:-

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.splash);
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use the:

```
setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

method.And following is the doc:

```
  /**
    * Set the background to a given Drawable, or remove the background. If the
    * background has padding, this View's padding is set to the background's
    * padding. However, when a background is removed, this View's padding isn't
    * touched. If setting the padding is desired, please use
    * {@link #setPadding(int, int, int, int)}.
    *
    * @param d The Drawable to use as the background, or null to remove the
    *        background
    */
```

Comment: this will work, but only when you extend the dialog box, not a fast solution but good one....

Answer (score 10):

One issue I found with all the existing answers is that the margins aren't preserved. This is because they all override the `android:windowBackground` attribute, which is responsible for margins, with a solid color. However, I did some digging in the Android SDK and found the default window background drawable, and modified it a bit to allow transparent dialogs.

First, copy /platforms/android-22/data/res/drawable/dialog_background_material.xml to your project. Or, just copy these lines into a new file:

```
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:inset="16dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        <solid android:color="?attr/colorBackground" />
    </shape>
</inset>
```

Notice that `android:color` is set to `?attr/colorBackground`. This is the default solid grey/white you see. To allow the color defined in `android:background` in your custom style to be transparent and show the transparency, all we have to do is change `?attr/colorBackground` to `@android:color/transparent`. Now it will look like this:

```
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:inset="16dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</inset>
```

After that, go to your theme and add this:

```
<style name="MyTransparentDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/newly_created_background_name</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/some_transparent_color</item>
</style>
```

Make sure to replace `newly_created_background_name` with the actual name of the drawable file you just created, and replace `some_transparent_color` with the desired transparent background.

After that all we need to do is set the theme. Use this when creating the `AlertDialog.Builder`:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.MyTransparentDialog);
```

Then just build, create, and show the dialog as usual!

Comment: I followed this with AppCompat AlertDialog but instead of using android:background, I chose to set a transparent color directly with the background drawable's android:color itself. Needed to do this because, setting android:background somehow left some areas still non transparent. But Thanks for sharing the technique!

Answer (score 7):

**Attention :** Don't use builder for changing background.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                                .setView(view)
                                .create();
dialog.show();dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

change to

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(view);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
dialog.show();
```

When using Dialog.builder, it's not giving `getWindow()` option in it.

Answer (score 4):

Try this in your code:

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

it will definately working...in my case...! my frend

Answer (score 4):

This is what I did to achieve translucency with AlertDialog.

Created a custom style:

```
<style name="TranslucentDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">#32FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

And then create the dialog with:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.TranslucentDialog);
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
```

Answer (score 3):

Same solution as zGnep but using xml:

```
android:background="@null"
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this code, it's works for me:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(),android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
dialog.show();
```

Comment: I think it would be more helful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
dialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent)
```

---

If you need to reuse this,

I would **recommend** creating an **extension function**. Something like
`extensions.kt`

```
import android.app.Dialog

fun Dialog.setTransparentBackground() {
    window?.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent)
}
```

and **use it on any dialog** by calling

```
dialog.setTransparentBackground()
```

Have some fun programming...

Answer (score 2):

If you use **Kotlin**, this code can help you:

```
dialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case solution works like this:

```
final Drawable drawable = new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT);
dialogAssignTag.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

Additionally, in xml file of your custom dialog:

```
android:alpha="0.8"
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you extended the `DialogFrament` class, you can set the theme with:

```
setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.customDialogTheme);
```

And then make the custom theme in your styles.xml file (see @LongLv's answer for parameters)

Don't forget to add `<item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>` if you want the dialog to close if the user touches outside the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Set these style code in style

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

And simply change false to true below line

```
<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
```

It will dim your background.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, nothing was working to apply a transparent background.

Only I used in my dialog onStart():

```
dialog?.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
```

But it was not taking any effect. I checked styles.xml, nothing linked to my problem.

Finally, when I was checking how my dialog is gets created I found that the navigation component was creating the dialog whenever I request the dialog fragment.

There In XML of navgraph.xml, I defined the dialog fragment as a fragment so, It was created as a fragment instead of a dialog. Changing that fragment to dialog made everything fall in place.

BTW: You cannot modify from fragment to dialog in the GUI of the navigation editor. You should change by hand in code.

This might be one of a cause when some effect on a dialog is not reflected in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

```
Window window = d.getWindow();
window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
```

this is my way, you can try!

Comment: This is deprecated now: @deprecated Blurring is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using a custom dialog with a custom class you need to change the transparency in the class add this line in the onCreate():

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ColorDrawable drawable = new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(ctx, android.R.color.transparent));
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `R.layout.themechanger` has no background color because by default the dialog has a default background color.

You also need to add `dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(newColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));`

And finally

```
<style name="TransparentDialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin you can use this code:

```
val dialog = Dialog(context)
dialog.window?.decorView?.background = null
```

Answer (score -1):

Kotlin way to create dialog with transparent background:

```
 Dialog(activity!!, R.style.LoadingIndicatorDialogStyle)
            .apply {
                // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
                setCancelable(true)
                setContentView(R.layout.define_your_custom_view_id_here)

                //access your custom view buttons/editText like below.z
                val createBt = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.clipboard_create_project)
                val cancelBt = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.clipboard_cancel_project)
                val clipboard_et = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.clipboard_et)
                val manualOption =
                    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.clipboard_manual_add_project_option)

                //if you want to perform any operation on the button do like this

                createBt.setOnClickListener {
                    //handle your button click here
                    val enteredData = clipboard_et.text.toString()
                    if (enteredData.isEmpty()) {
                        Utils.toast("Enter project details")
                    } else {
                        navigateToAddProject(enteredData, true)
                        dismiss()
                    }
                }

                cancelBt.setOnClickListener {
                    dismiss()
                }
                manualOption.setOnClickListener {
                    navigateToAddProject("", false)
                    dismiss()
                }
                show()
            }
```

Create LoadingIndicatorDialogStyle in style.xml like this:

```
<style name="LoadingIndicatorDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/black_transperant</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <!--<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/MaterialDialogSheetAnimation</item>-->
</style>
```