# Black bands on custom dialogs

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm customizing an alert dialog, with a different UI. Here is an example.

[image]

As you can see there are two black bands (highlighted with red rectangulars) I would like to remove.

It weird because the main layout show match the parent one, as you can see from the xml below.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/lytDialog_takeNowDialog"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_side_space"
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_side_space"
android:background="@color/yellow"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="@dimen/default_side_space"
    android:text="Are you sure?"
    android:textColor="@color/dialog_text_color"
    android:textSize="@dimen/dialog_text_size" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lytShowAlert_takeNowDialog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/black_gradient"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/default_side_space" android:visibility="gone">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkShowAlert_takeNowDialog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="@string/dont_show_alert"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/dialog_yes_no_size" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/no_dialog"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/space_among_buttons"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:background="@drawable/yellow_gradient"
        android:padding="@dimen/default_side_space"
        android:text="No"
        android:textColor="@color/dialog_text_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/dialog_yes_no_size" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/yes_dialog"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/space_among_buttons"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:background="@drawable/yellow_gradient"
        android:padding="@dimen/default_side_space"
        android:text="Yes"
        android:textColor="@color/dialog_text_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/dialog_yes_no_size" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Anyone knows the solution to remove them please?

Comment: that is because they are part of the default dialog UI. I've found that if you want full control of Dialog styles it is easier to make a an Activity with some transparent space around the outside so it appears to the user like a dialog, but is actually technically an Activity. I came to this conclusion while fighting a similar issue to what you face now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove black panel, change the appTheme(Actually dialog theme.).

[Dialog with transparent background in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795078/dialog-with-transparent-background-in-android)