# set Transparent background to alertdialog in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to show an alert dialog with a transparent background.

My code for the alert dialog is:

```
AlertDialog.Builder imageDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SubProducts.this);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)SubProducts.this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cust_toast_layout,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2));

ImageView image = (ImageView)layout.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
image.setPadding(0, 20, 0, 0);
imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, loader, image);

TextView tprice=(TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.pricetext);
tprice.setText("$ "+pricedouble);

TextView tvdprh=(TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

tvdprh.setText(prohd);

WebView wv=(WebView)layout.findViewById(R.id.webview);

Spanned sub=Html.fromHtml(descp);
String s = "<html><head><style type='text/css' >@font-face {font-family:'myfont';src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/ABeeZee-Regular.ttf');}body {margin:0px;color:000000;font-family: myfont;"
        + "text-align: justify;}</style></head><body>"
        + sub
        + "</body></html>";

wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("", s, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
wv.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
wv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
wv.setPadding(5, 25, 5, 0);

ImageView imgcartl=(ImageView)layout.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
imgcartl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cartlines);

ImageView brobutton=(ImageView)layout.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
brobutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intentlabl = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Label.class);
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putString("url", image_urlpdf);
b.putBoolean("isDialog", true);
intentlabl.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intentlabl);

}
        });

ImageView shobutton=(ImageView)layout.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);

shobutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//intent code
        }
        });

ImageView addbutton=(ImageView)layout.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
addbutton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.addicon);
addbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        passingid.add(prodid);

Product prodobj=new Product();
prodobj.setId(passingid);


new LongRunningGetIO4().execute(pricedouble, prodid);
}
        });

imageDialog.setView(layout);

imageDialog.create();
imageDialog.show();
```

My background image contains rounded corners, but unfortunately, the pop-up is appearing with a rectangular white background. How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 105):

define what follows in the `styles.xml` file

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

and pass it as argument to the `AlertDialog` constructor

```
AlertDialog.Builder imageDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SubProducts.this, R.style.CustomDialog);
```

Or programmatically, through the `Dialog` instance you can call

```
myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
```

Comment: thanq blackbelt it worked.But  showing black background now..I need transparent.

Comment: it is strange. has R.layout.cust_toast_layout an black backround color?

Comment: yes I have added snapshot of alert dialog in my question.Plz have a look.

Comment: try adding this inside  the style : <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>

Comment: can you try with a Dialog instead of an AlertDialog?

Comment: yes @blackbelt Now Converted to dialog instead of alert dialog,,, now can you tell me about background to transparent??

Comment: changing in Dialog does not fix your issue?

Comment: belt I have edited my question with snapshot.Plz have a look.

Comment: Call requires API level 11

Comment: this work on Android 5.0 +, but at least does not work on Android 4.4

Comment: @Blackbelt, see my demo project under Android studio 2.2 : https://www.dropbox.com/s/63u4pywdnvlgy2l/demo.zip?dl=0

Comment: I get a `may produce nullpointer` warning when using `myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))`

Comment: @ClassA getWindow may return null

Comment: The warning points to `setBackgroundDrawable`, but yes I understand what you are saying. So I can just do `if (myDialog.getWindow() != null) {myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))}`

Comment: Well this works for me while ContextThemeWrapper not.. Strange but thanks~

Comment: I tested both suggestions: They both work BUT they seem to replace the dialog's `Drawable` and it ends up losing its rounded corners plus, if you set the size with `getWindow().setLayout(400,400)`, the dialog isn't square anymore afterwards.

Answer (score 46):

One more solution:

When using `Alertdialog.builder` - Its not giving `getwindow()` option in it.
So we can make it work like this:

```
AlertDialog dialog = builderScan.create();
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dialog.show();
```

And your Background of `AlertDialog` will be transperent.

Comment: This is the exact way to do it. Way to go. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of this:

```
imageDialog.create();
imageDialog.show();
```

you could try doing something like this:

```
AlertDialog imageDialogAlert = imageDialog.create();
imageDialogAlert.show();
imageDialogAlert.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Comment: it is showing the error:The method getWindow() is undefined for the type AlertDialog.Builder

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Please have a look at the updated answer, it should work now.

Answer (score 4):

Call this,

```
customDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

just before

```
customDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to remove white background from the dialog layout then you just add:

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

If you also want remove window background translucent colour for the dialog then you need to add both lines:

```
dialog.getWindow().setDimAmount(0f);    
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Answer (score 2):

````
val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()
      dialog.window!!.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
        dialog.setView(view)
        dialog.show()```
````

Comment: Please consider adding some descriptions to your solution. Code only answers are discouraged on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected AlertDialog(Context context) {
    this(context, com.android.internal.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
}

public Builder(Context context) {
    this(context, com.android.internal.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below changes the background layout.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();

View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);

final AlertDialog alertDio = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .setView(layout)
                        .show();

alertDio.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.parseColor("#801b5e20")));
```

Answer (score 0):

First set a custom theme for alert dialog in theme.xml

```
<style name="YourThemeName" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">#CC8800</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>

</style>
```

after this set this theme on your AlertDialog

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity(),R.style.YourThemeName;
            alertDialog.setView(R.layout.your_custom_view);
            alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
            alertDialog.create();
            alertDialog.show();
```