# how to remove alertdialogbox additional background

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

below is the image of my dialog box executed on android 19,
i want to remove that red marked background area. How to remove that in android 19, please help, 
Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186818/set-transparent-background-to-alertdialog-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got it using this code

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_Alert);
    builder.setTitle("Message");
    builder.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_appicon);
    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });
    builder.setMessage(status);//TODO put real question
    builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {

        }
    });
    builder.show();
```

Comment: previously i was using only "AlertDialog" then i changed to "AlertDialog.Builder" and changed code as above

Answer (score 0):

When using `Alertdialog.builder` - Its not giving getwindow() option in it. So we can make it work like this:

```
AlertDialog dialog = builderScan.create();
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dialog.show();
```

And your Background of `AlertDialog` will be transperent.

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186818/set-transparent-background-to-alertdialog-in-android)