# Remove main background

Tags: android

I am setting background for login screen in java with following line:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.bg_wood);
```

But when user logins to app,i have to remove this background.How can I do this ?

Comment: see [Dialog with transparent background in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795078/dialog-with-transparent-background-in-android) probably help

Comment: hmm,guess open a new activity best for this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
getActivity().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(0);
```

Or

```
getActivity().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(new ColorDrawableResource(R.color.transparent));
```

Comment: It causes crash.Resources not found exception.

Option 2 : giving compiler error

Comment: @Okan what about  `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));` or `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null);`?

Comment: It did black background

Comment: so "i have to remove this background." means change it to WHITE color doesn't it ?

Comment: so change android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT to android.graphics.Color.WHITE

Comment: use this `window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);`

Answer (score 0):

make background white using this code in oncreate method

**getActivity().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));**

you can change background color by changing color of ColorDrawable.