# How to display animation in dialog android

Tags: android, dialog, android-animation

I want to display animation in dialog.

when the dialog is opened the animation start, i want only animation and text "Loading..." without title ,buttons or background to the dialog but alpha black to the backwards layout.

My Layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff111214">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/loader_image"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/loader"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/wait"
        android:layout_below="@id/loader_image"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My animation code:

```
    <rotate android:duration="500"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="55"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way is to use [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) (there's one in Support Library also, so shouldn't be impossible even if you want to support old targets).
Here's quick sample:

```
public class ProgressDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_progress_dialog, container, false);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        final View progressItem = getView().findViewById(R.id.loader_image);

        progressItem.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.rotation));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        final View progressItem = getView().findViewById(R.id.loader_image);

        progressItem.clearAnimation();
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#88111214">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/loader_image"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/wait"
            android:layout_below="@id/loader_image"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            final ProgressDialogFragment dialogFragment = new ProgressDialogFragment();

            dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "ProgressDialog");
        }
    }
}
```

Result is:

[image]

Another way is to use outdated [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html), set your own layout, theme (like here [dialog transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795078/dialog-with-transparent-background-in-android)) and create some wrapper class to control the animation. It's error-prone, because code structure will not be clear and there might be some issues with Resume / Pause. I would recommend to use first way.