# Android drawable background corner not remove

Tags: android, drawable

I am applying a drawable background in our xml layout but it also contains border how to remove it ?

When i put the corners then it apply the corner but it not apply the corner on whole layout (means not content goes outside the border area).

[image: custom dialog box image]

This is my drawable file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

<solid
    android:color="#fff">

</solid>

<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="@color/block_button_bg">

</stroke>

<corners
    android:radius="10dp">

</corners>


</shape>
```

and this my xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/custom_dialog_bg">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtDiaTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_dialog_title"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtDiaMsg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:text="@string/app_dialog_desc"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:background="@color/alarm_color"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/yes"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/yes"
        android:textColor="#0C76EE"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/alarm_color"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/no"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/no"
        android:textColor="#0C76EE"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you do every thing good. but you must use transparent theme for your dialog, or set background window of dialog transparent.
Like this:

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new       ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

or use [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795078/dialog-with-transparent-background-in-android).

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below one ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

    <corners android:radius="10dip" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@android:color/white" />

</shape>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @UjjwalJha, please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161448/how-to-make-layout-with-rounded-corners/16161658#16161658

Comment: When i see the our Android Studio preview then it both previous and new Code showing good layout.
But when i apply this drawable in our layout and check then this problem occur.

Can you check my xml layout code?

Comment: @UjjwalJha, let me check and let you know.

Comment: I guess you never checked

Comment: I have laughed .