# Card looking Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

I'm making a Dialog which has a card-like corners. But I can't quite make it look like a card.I can make corners but still part above the red radius color is being shown on the dialog. I tried everything but I can't make it work. Can someone help me? My main layout is cardView and I put my shape layout in the background of the Linear Layout.[image]

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
<stroke
    android:width="6dip"
    android:color="#f45"/>
<corners android:radius="15dip"/>
<padding
    android:bottom="0dip"
    android:left="0dip"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="0dip"/>
```

[image]

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:text="Bits Please"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:foreground="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#030202"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="text"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
           />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
           />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
          />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795078/dialog-with-transparent-background-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing of this worked for me, However I just added this line of code to the CardView Layout.-> app:cardCornerRadius="amount"

No backgrounds,themes,styles or anything needed. Hope this helps someone

and this in the code in the activity:

dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

Answer (score 2):

Use this, along with your code -

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

and add transparent background in cardview too -

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="250dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:baselineAligned="false"
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 android:paddingLeft="10dp"
 android:paddingRight="10dp"
 android:background="@android:color/transparent" >
```

Comment: Still no progress. Btw this is the code:

    [code]public void showAboutAlert() {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.about_us_layout);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.show();
    } [code]

Tried moving setBackgroundDrawable around the code, still no progress.