# Need transparent background like this

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, transparent

Need to make a layout like this.
Below is an alert box which has a transparent background containing spinner and a button below.

[image]

i ve tried this as far.

this is the layout file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

>


<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:paddingBottom="50dp">

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/selectCity_xspn"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="75dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/selectCity_xspn"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/selectCtgry_xspn" />
```

```
<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_marginTop="300dp"


    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

This is the java class where i ve used the transparent option at many places but it doesnt work.

accessing the function at the bottom in the following button.

```
 customdialog_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            onCreateDialog2().show();


        }
    });

 public Dialog onCreateDialog2() {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Registeration.this);



    View dialog_view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);

    //dialog_view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    builder.setView(dialog_view);

    selectCity_spn=(Spinner)dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.selectCity_xspn);
    selectCtgry_spn=(Spinner)dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.selectCtgry_xspn);


    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this.getBaseContext(), R.array.selectCity_spn, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    assert selectCity_spn != null;
    selectCity_spn.setAdapter(adapter);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this.getBaseContext(), R.array.selectCtgry_spn, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    assert selectCtgry_spn != null;
    selectCtgry_spn.setAdapter(adapter2);

    View v = getWindow().getDecorView();
    v.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    return builder.create();
}
```

Comment: take a look at

Dialog with transparent background in Android

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795078/dialog-with-transparent-background-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do

```
Dialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
return dialog;
```

Comment: where in the code do i put it,  there is no variable called 'dialog'.!

Comment: at the bottom of the onCreateDialog2() method. just replace return builder.create() with these.

Comment: thanks bro.!! u r awesome.!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
Dialog dialog1 = new Dialog(Main3Activity.this);

                dialog1.setCancelable(true);
                dialog1.setContentView(view1);

                dialog1.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set background transparent of any layout or any view or any component by adding this code in XML

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```