# Custom Dialog background not transparent corners

Tags: android, image, dialog, custom-view

I'm using a custom dialog with an image as a background. The problem is that the image has round corners and when they appear (during runtime) they are white.

I've tried:

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Here is my code.

```
            Context context = Deck_Creator.this;
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.content_deck_view);
            Deck_Big_Screen_Adapter deck_big_screen_adapter = new Deck_Big_Screen_Adapter(Deck_Creator.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, _Custom_Hash.getHash_Table(), Image_Loader);
            GridView Deck_Cards = (GridView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dv_grid_cards);
            Deck_Cards.setAdapter(deck_big_screen_adapter);
            dialog.show();
```

Here is how it looks now:

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrU4l.jpg)

Comment: check here for possible Dialog Transparent solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795078/dialog-with-transparent-background-in-android

Comment: is the image a png?

Comment: post the layout and also the image should have transparency itself, you could use a nine-patch for different screens https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html#&sourceDensity=320&name=example

Comment: yes the image is .png