# how to remove layout background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, android-cardview

I am trying to remove background from popup dialog, but it's showing `white color` behind the **cardview**

> `background = @null` is not working

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/lnrMstr"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#0D000000">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_2sdp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `#0D000000` should be either `#00000000`, or `@android:color/transparent`. Also, use `dp` to set the CardView margins.

Comment: If you have a white bg color on `#0D000000` then this bg color might be related to a parent of the `LinearLayout`, since `#000000` is black and not white.

Comment: background #00000000 i\or transparent is not working for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need to remove that  color from background just set dialog window background as transparent.

add in code:

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

reference :[more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795078/dialog-with-transparent-background-in-android)

Comment: i would suggest first proper search you will get most of answer. if still you get problem then post with efforts.

Comment: @VishalThakkar What is different in you answer and this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10795234/5995648) answer should different, otherwise juts put as comment.

Comment: @Arbaz.in check comment i was already commented first.

Comment: @vishal .  Yes i saw that and its not about the who comment first but if you're refering any other people answer .you should also attached the link along with the solution as it goes to whom so ever is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

try this by edit the color `#0D000000` to `#00000000`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/lnrMstr"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#00000000">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_2sdp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```