# Dialog - It changes status bar color

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-theme, android-dialog, android-statusbar

I am trying to create and show a fullscreen dialog. I want to create some animation using this custom dialog layout. This code works on a fragment not activity.

My code is below :

```
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());
            LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
            linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(-1, -1));
            linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

            dialog.requestWindowFeature(1);
            dialog.setContentView(linearLayout);
            Window dialogWindow = dialog.getWindow();
            dialogWindow.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
            dialogWindow.setDimAmount(0.0f);
            dialogWindow.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            // View.WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            dialogWindow.setLayout(-1, -1);

            dialog.show();
```

The screenshots are below:

[image]

After dialog.show status bar color changes. 
[image]

R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light doesn't work for me. It changes status bar as light gray :)

How can I show a full transparent custom dialog?

Comment: Test case remove `dialogWindow.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);`

Comment: and use  this **`dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);`**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795078/dialog-with-transparent-background-in-android

Comment: @NileshRathod This setting is not enough. I use Theme_Holo_Light_NoActionBar_Fullscreen theme, but it removes icons in status bar. :/

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.setContentView(layout_file);
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: I want to use full screen dialog. But this is not.

Comment: Use RelativeLayout and modify last line of my code as below--       dialog.getWindow().setLayout(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);