# corner is not transparent in dialog or alert dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

[image: screenshot]

Note: I tried with dialog and `alertdialog` both.

Example: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795078/dialog-with-transparent-background-in-android) I tried so far.

Code:

```
 private Dialog mDialog;

 public void showCategoryDialog() {
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.row_category_dialog_layout, null);
        findViewById();
        init();
        setClickListener();


        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.dialogBoxStyle);
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);


        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.new_category), null);
        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(context.getString(R.string.cancel), null);


        recyclerView();
        search();
        mDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        mDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        mDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                Button button = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                Button buttonNegative = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        isEditPayment = false;
                        showDialogBox(0);
                    }
                });

                buttonNegative.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        });


        mDialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: How your output is come? Show it

Comment: @Piyush please check screenshot in question

Comment: looks like your root layout have white background color set .. Check your Layout's root element .

Comment: Have you applied any background to _row_category_dialog_layout_?

Comment: @Piyush No, that white color is coming I think because of alert dialog. I haven't passed anywhere white color

Comment: I have CardView root, and I haven't passed anything

Comment: @ADM I have CardView root, and I haven't passed anything

Comment: Add the layout with question ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a `AlertDialog` whit transparent window you can use from `DialogFragment` and set:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.NewDialog);


    }
```

NewDialog in styles.xml :

```
<style name="NewDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/dark</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/lighgray2</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">13dp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:minWidth">250dp</item>
        <item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>
        <item name="android:height">20dp</item>
    </style>
```

Also in `DialogFragment` you can set custom layout that with transparent window display what you want.

More complete example :

```
public class TVShowFragment extends DialogFragment {

    RecyclerView rv;
    TellListAdaptor adapter;
    List<TellListModel> tellListModels = new ArrayList<>();

    public static String CustomerName;
    public static boolean isCustomer;
    private TellListModel tellListModel;
    int newMsgPosition;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_custom_layout, container);
        //RECYCER
        rv = rootView.findViewById(R.id.mRecyerID);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));

        //ADAPTER
        adapter = new TellListAdaptor(tellListModels);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);


            if (FragmentRoute.OperatorPhons.size() != 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < FragmentRoute.OperatorPhons.size(); i++) {
                    tellListModel = new TellListModel(FragmentRoute.OperatorPhons.get(i), CustomerName);
                    tellListModels.add(tellListModel);
                    newMsgPosition = tellListModels.size() - 1;
                    adapter.notifyItemInserted(newMsgPosition);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }


        this.getDialog().setTitle( CustomerName);

        TextView textView = getDialog().findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        textView.setTextSize(15);
        textView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.NewDialog);


    }
}
```

call it :

```
final TVShowFragment tv = new TVShowFragment();
                    tv.show(MainActivity.fm, "TV_tag");
```

Comment: what is setstyle and I have separate class for dialog which start from activity

Comment: I edited my answer with a more complete example. Hope this will help you!