# using vector file as dialog background shows black background on remaining part

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: this image is a dialog with a vector background]

The vector asset I used had transparent background.

Now my problem is marked in blue, the background is grey(which is circled) but I want it to be transparent.
The same problem I'm facing with rounded corners for dialog box

I searched through internet but didn't find any solution for my problem.

This is my XML file for dialog box

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="409dp"
android:layout_height="260dp"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/ic_dialogback">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_textviewback"
    android:fontFamily="@font/amaranth_bold"
    android:text="Add Player Names"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/ply1"
    android:textColorHint="#768176"
    android:fontFamily="@font/amaranth_bold"
    android:textColor="#03A9F4"
    android:background="@drawable/edittextback"
    android:hint="Player 1"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/ply2"
    android:textColorHint="#768176"
    android:fontFamily="@font/amaranth_bold"
    android:textColor="#03A9F4"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittextback"
    android:hint="Player 2"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Let's Play"
        android:id="@+id/lplay"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:background="@drawable/imageback"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Discard"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/dis"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:background="@drawable/imageback"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please also take a look at: [Dialog with transparent background in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795078/dialog-with-transparent-background-in-android).
Perhaps you could also use the same line programmatically:

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

while building the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to fake it with a fragment!
Replace your dialog with a fragment and set a black color as background with transparency, like: **#77000000**

In fact, you're going to start a fragment which it has custom view in center (just like dialog) and a transparent color for background.