# Dim everything except loading screen

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android. Ok so what I want to do is dim everything except the lottieAnimationView whenever I make the lottieAnimationView visible and also make everything back to normal when I turn lottieAnimationView gone. I tried a piece of code but it doesn't work

Edit: Maybe its possible through making the lottieanimationview visible inside an alert dialog box so can someone provide the code for that.

Comment: can u plz add reference code what u r trying to do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Custom Dialog which contains LottieAnimationView through which you can achieve desire output.

You can get an idea that how to create Custom Dialog using below link.

[How to create a Custom Dialog box in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android)

[Dialog with transparent background in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795078/dialog-with-transparent-background-in-android)

Comment: thanks it worked