How to add a vector drawable with rounded corners to relative layout without background?
i created a rounded corners vector and try to add it as a drawable to a relative layout
but the corners aren't visible because of a an unwanted background that is underneath this layout.
i have a vector generated in figma that is called inner:
vector + android studio pallete
and this is how i added it to my layout :
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/inner"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="326dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/inner"
    android:viewportWidth="350"
    android:viewportHeight="326"
    android:clipToOutline="true"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="92dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/circle_icon"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/green_checkmark">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/check"
                android:layout_width="44dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/vector"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/baseline_check_24"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="302dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/icon">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_text"
            android:layout_width="302dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="@string/you_re_all_set"
            android:textColor="@color/black50"
            android:fontFamily="@font/inter_700"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="5sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/subtitle_text"
        android:layout_width="302dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="302dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:text="@string/the_app_is_connected"
            android:textColor="@color/black50"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="5sp"
            android:translationY="-2.32sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/start_exercising_button"
        android:layout_width="302dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:layout_below="@id/subtitle_text"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/button_text"
            android:layout_width="119dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:text="@string/start_exercising"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="3sp"
            android:translationY="-1.52sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            />



    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>


android studio design
physical phone design
debug photo added tint to show the problem
why is there a white background and how to get rid of it?
the root element is the relative layout where is this background coming from?

Looks like you're showing your layout in a dialog?

Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795078/dialog-with-transparent-background-in-android
