# Android Dialog without transparent margins (fullscreen)

Tags: android, dialog, fullscreen, android-alertdialog, borderless

I have an alert dialog created using the alertdialog builder. I want to remove the space in the left and right of the dialog... basically extend it from side to side. I know I could you an activity instead of a dialog, but I want to keep the button style and implementing that button style in an activity requires making a layout for different SDKs, which is not convenient in the long run.

Why I need it full width?
Because I need to display AdMob ads and if they are not full width the ads will not load.

Any help is appreciated as I have tried all kinds of theme properties...

Thanks,
Adrian

PS: Here is my current code for creating the dialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.DialogTheme));
    alertDialogBuilder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dial_dialog, null);

    AdView adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    if (!application.getLicense().isValid()) {
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequestWrapper(this));
    }

    alertDialogBuilder.setView(view);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.dial_dialog_title).setCancelable(false);
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.dial_dialog_message_positive_text, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alertDialogBuilder.setNeutralButton(R.string.dial_dialog_message_neutral_text, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(R.string.dial_dialog_message_negative_text, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
    alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

PS2: Here is an image with what I need... http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=f3aed38
I need to loose all the space with red. I don't have any problems with the space marked in yellow. (it can be kept or it can be removed)

Comment: its better if you use transperent activity with animation...

Comment: I would rather use an activity given I can use Dialog themed buttons and title bar. Can that be done?

Comment: yeah..you can do that..but you want transperent borders so that you can see previous activity content..if so..then you have to use transperent theme activity..and you can remove title ans status bar too.

Comment: No that is the point... I do not want the borders. Basically I want something the size of an activity, but with the look of a dialog.

Comment: then go for dialouge activity or dialougefragment window...

Comment: The problem with the activity with Dialog theme is that I cannot add stuff like dialog style buttons or title without too much hassle. That is why I want to do it with Dialog rather then Activity with Dialog theme.

Comment: show me screenshot what you want?

Comment: I wanted to add one, but I am unable to add photos as I do not have the needed reputation...

Comment: I need a dialog that would cover the screen just like an activity. Right now dialogs come floating and have that transparent margin where you can see what is in the background. I want the dialog to cover that too... I want the dialog to be full-screen.

Comment: www.tiikoni.com..upload here nd paste link here.

Comment: Added link in the question...

Comment: use dialouge fragment for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know a little bit late to come back with an answer, but following the recipes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836938/remove-border-padding-from-dialog?noredirect=1&lq=1) I managed to solved almost everything. Basically I have the following Dialog theme:

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/screen_background_selector_light</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">100%</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">100%</item>
</style>
```

**Note the reference to screen_background_selector_light which means I also had to add screen_background_selector_light.xml and (its dependency background_holo_light.xml).**

Other that that I only had to specify the activity will use this new theme:

```
<activity android:name=".zom.xyz.app.activity.MyActivity_" android:label="@string/activity_title" android:theme="@style/DialogTheme"/>
```

And of course create it as any other activity.

As for the other need I had... easy buttons I did it this way. Here is the layout of the activity

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    INSERT_DIALOG_CONTENT_HERE

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/activity_message_negative_text"/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/skipButton"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/activity_message_neutral_text"/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/correctButton"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/activity_message_positive_text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Using this layout and theme will give you the exact feel of a dialog while giving it full width.

Answer (score 0):

1 )Create your own dialog  extended from Dialog and in constructor set style, something like this:

```
public MyDialog(Context c, Event e) {
        super(c, android.R.style.Theme_Light);
}
```

or

2) when creating instanse, set style:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.MyDialogTheme);
```

example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8880806/1991579)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have edited my initial question with the actual code I use to initialize the dialog. I have already tried the styles from the example in the custom theme I have (named DialogTheme), but they do not work.