# Slide a layout up from bottom of screen

Tags: android, layout, uislider

I have a layout hidden from the view. On a button click I want it to slide up from the bottom pushing the entire screen contents upwards, very similar to how whatsapp shows emoticons panel in chat screen.

I have seen SlidingDrawer, that dosen't work for me. It requires an image as an handle which is shown at the center of the screen, I don't want that. It also slides over the existing screen content, I am looking for a way to move the existing content upwards.

**Update 1:**

I tried using the animations as suggested by Sanket Kachhela. But the hidden layout is never shown. Here is the code.

**Layout (activity_main.xml):**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

     <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/hello_world" 
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Slide up / down"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:onClick="slideUpDown"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/hidden_panel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_below="@id/main_screen">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Activity (MainActivity.java):**

```
package com.example.slideuplayout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ViewGroup hiddenPanel;
private boolean isPanelShown;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    hiddenPanel = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.hidden_panel);
    hiddenPanel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    isPanelShown = false;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void slideUpDown(final View view) {
    if(!isPanelShown) {
        // Show the panel
        Animation bottomUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.bottom_up);

        hiddenPanel.startAnimation(bottomUp);
        hiddenPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        isPanelShown = true;
    }
    else {
        // Hide the Panel
        Animation bottomDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.bottom_down);

        hiddenPanel.startAnimation(bottomDown);
        hiddenPanel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        isPanelShown = false;
    }
}

}
```

**Animations:**

bottom_up.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate 
       android:fromYDelta="75%p"
       android:toYDelta="0%p"
       android:fillAfter="true"
       android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

bottom_down.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate 
    android:fromYDelta="0%p" 
    android:toYDelta="100%p" 
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

Any ideas how this can be done ?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried answer?

Comment: Your layout hidden_panel might be going behind other layout. Call `hiddenPanel.bringToFront()` before starting animation and see if it works. Also let us know, are you getting hidden_panel view in graphical layout for `activity_main.xml` ?

Comment: @Babar means when u click on sliding up/down button the hidden layout should be expanded or collapsed accordingly?i phone type slider?

Comment: @Babar does my answer work?

Comment: You can look at https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/SlidingDrawer, which mekes it possible for you to slide from any side.

Comment: @Babar this is probably a late reply but looks like none of these answers have been accepted? Did any of these answers work for you?

Answer (score 162):

Use these animations:

**bottom_up.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <translate android:fromYDelta="75%p" android:toYDelta="0%p" 
    android:fillAfter="true"
 android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

**bottom_down.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<translate android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="100%p" android:fillAfter="true"
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:duration="500" />

</set>
```

Use this code in your activity for hiding/animating your view:

```
Animation bottomUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),
            R.anim.bottom_up);
ViewGroup hiddenPanel = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.hidden_panel);
hiddenPanel.startAnimation(bottomUp);
hiddenPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: I tried using the above code but the hidden view never showed up. I have updated the question and added the layout and java code. Thanks.

Comment: @sanket hi I have used your code it works good but I have to make thread to sleep for a while then I have to use anim of bottom down , so can u help me out how to do that?

Comment: i think you can uset startOffset .. see this doc http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#attr_android:startOffset

Comment: Before the animation start there is a blank space where my view ll go. any idea  ?

Comment: you should have to apply animation(pull from bottom) to view 1 also.

Comment: Hi...How can I write toYDelta in percentage in java file?

Comment: @AditiParikh i guess, we not able to change value of anim xml, and as this answer is now old, so you can use now objectanimator and value animator, 
you can try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/23497119/942224

Comment: Why use 75%p instead of 100%p in bottom_up? I am just curious

Comment: @cnnrznn i have not to showed up views from very bottom.. so i put 75%p  but you can user 100%p if you want to views up from very bottom.

Comment: How to implement it in **setOnScrollListener**

Comment: If you're using a `DialogFragment`, you may also want to align the `Dialog` or `AlertDialog` to the bottom of the screen, to make it behave like a `BottomSheetDialogFragment`. You can use the guidance from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467026/changing-position-of-the-dialog-on-screen-android#9467151 and put that code in `DialogFragment.onStart()` (override function).

Answer (score 42):

You were close. The key is to have the hidden layout inflate to `match_parent` in both height and weight. Simply start it off as `View.GONE`. This way, using the percentage in the animators works properly.

**Layout (activity_main.xml):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:onClick="slideUpDown"
        android:text="Slide up / down" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/hidden_panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:onClick="slideUpDown" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Activity (MainActivity.java):**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;

public class OffscreenActivity extends Activity {
    private View hiddenPanel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        hiddenPanel = findViewById(R.id.hidden_panel);
    }

    public void slideUpDown(final View view) {
        if (!isPanelShown()) {
            // Show the panel
            Animation bottomUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                    R.anim.bottom_up);

            hiddenPanel.startAnimation(bottomUp);
            hiddenPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            // Hide the Panel
            Animation bottomDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                    R.anim.bottom_down);

            hiddenPanel.startAnimation(bottomDown);
            hiddenPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private boolean isPanelShown() {
        return hiddenPanel.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
    }

}
```

Only other thing I changed was in `bottom_up.xml`. Instead of

```
android:fromYDelta="75%p"
```

I used:

```
android:fromYDelta="100%p"
```

But that's a matter of preference, I suppose.

Comment: This did not work for me, the hidden panel pops up but the already shown text on the screen was being hidden and the 'slide up / down' button was moving from the corner to the centre of screen horizontally.

Comment: Can you tell why sliding layout can not cover all other components in parent layout? I sucesfuly implemented your code. But for my requirements I added some other linear layouts to parent layout. But when sliding layout appear, it can not cover these layouts

Comment: @gabby You may need to set `android:zAdjustment="top"` on your `Animation` or `AnimtionSet`.

Comment: it didn't work. .my anims are like that:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate 
    android:fromYDelta="0%p" 
    android:toYDelta="100%p" 
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:duration="400"
    android:zAdjustment="top" />
</set>

Comment: Excuse me Paul. I dont understand what you mean. Yes I have 2 xml in anims folder for up down animation. I added android:zAdjustment="top" to these file and it didnt work. Since yesterday I am searching for this

Comment: I manage that by using bringToFront() in java. I wonder It is possible to do that in xml

Comment: `<set xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:zAdjustment="top">`

Comment: This should be marked right answer. Thanks @PaulBurke

Comment: @Paul This answer helped me a lot, but how would I get this to work on a scrollview so the hidden panel will show at the bottom of the screen no matter where i am in the scroll view?

Comment: @user968808 I'm not sure what you mean, but it doesn't sound like the same question. Perhaps you should post a new question with better details. Feel free to link back here.

Comment: @PaulBurke This is a great starting point for me but (as the OP also requires), this solution does not *push* the existing content upwards. Instead, it seems the `hiddenPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` line make a **sudden** space for hiddenPanel to grow into - ie, the existing content is pushed up instantly rather than gradually. Do you if/how it's possible to make it so that the existing content really is pushed up by the emergence of hiddenPanel?

Answer (score 9):

You just need to add some line in your app, please find it from below link:

[Show and hide a View with a slide up/down animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765938/show-and-hide-a-view-with-a-slide-up-down-animation/32264906#32264906)

Just add an animation to your layout like this:

```
mLayoutTab.animate()
  .translationYBy(120)
  .translationY(0)
  .setDuration(getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_mediumAnimTime));
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is what worked in the end for me.

**Layouts:**

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/slideButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Slide up / down"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:onClick="slideUpDown"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

hidden_panel.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/hidden_panel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Test" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Java:**
    package com.example.slideuplayout;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ViewGroup hiddenPanel;
private ViewGroup mainScreen;
private boolean isPanelShown;
private ViewGroup root;

int screenHeight = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mainScreen = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.main_screen);
    ViewTreeObserver vto = mainScreen.getViewTreeObserver(); 
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
        @Override 
        public void onGlobalLayout() { 
            screenHeight = mainScreen.getHeight();
            mainScreen.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this); 
        } 
    }); 

    root = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.root);

    hiddenPanel = (ViewGroup)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.hidden_panel, root, false);
    hiddenPanel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    root.addView(hiddenPanel);

    isPanelShown = false;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void slideUpDown(final View view) {
    if(!isPanelShown) {
        // Show the panel
        mainScreen.layout(mainScreen.getLeft(),
                          mainScreen.getTop() - (screenHeight * 25/100), 
                          mainScreen.getRight(),
                          mainScreen.getBottom() - (screenHeight * 25/100));



        hiddenPanel.layout(mainScreen.getLeft(), mainScreen.getBottom(), mainScreen.getRight(), screenHeight);
        hiddenPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        Animation bottomUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.bottom_up);

        hiddenPanel.startAnimation(bottomUp);

        isPanelShown = true;
    }
    else {
        isPanelShown = false;

        // Hide the Panel
        Animation bottomDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.bottom_down);
        bottomDown.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
                isPanelShown = false;

                mainScreen.layout(mainScreen.getLeft(),
                          mainScreen.getTop() + (screenHeight * 25/100), 
                          mainScreen.getRight(),
                          mainScreen.getBottom() + (screenHeight * 25/100));

                hiddenPanel.layout(mainScreen.getLeft(), mainScreen.getBottom(), mainScreen.getRight(), screenHeight);
            }
        });
        hiddenPanel.startAnimation(bottomDown);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: @Babar what is the root

Comment: It is the parent layout encapsulating main_screen. Seems like in trying to remove the excess UI elements I ended up removing it from the code I have pasted here. It was either Linear or Relative layout.

Comment: Its an accepted answer and does not have the root element and nothing???? how can this be accepted??

Answer (score 5):

Use this layout. If you want to animate the main view shrinking you'll need to add animation to the height of the hidden bar, buy it may be good enough to use the translate animation on the bar, and have the main view height jump instead of animate.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:onClick="slideUpDown"
        android:text="Slide up / down" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/hidden_panel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#fcc"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: On the 'slide up' button click, I am programmatically  changing the position of main_screen and the hidden panel upwards by calling the layout method, then I am calling the startAnimation on hidden view. This makes the hidden panel pop up into the place. But for some reason the button inside the panel is not showing up. The panel is empty. Any clues why the button is not showing up?

Comment: You should just change visibility of the hidden panel to visible. From your description, I am guessing that the button visibility was changed, or the button width/height is zero

Answer (score 4):

Ok, there are two possible approaches. The simplest - is to use a [sliding menu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) library. It allows creating a bottom sliding menu, it can animate the top container to make bottom visible, it suports both dragging it with your finger, or animating it programmatically via button (StaticDrawer).

Harder way - if you want to use Animations, as was already suggested. With animations you must FIRST change your layouts. So try first to make your layout change to the final state without any animations whatsoever. Because it is very likely that you are not laying out your views properly in RelativeLayout, so even though you show your bottom view, it remains obscured by the top one. Once you achieved proper layout change - all you need to do is to is to remember translations before layout and apply translate animation AFTER layout.

Comment: the button on the hidden panel was not showing up, probably because the panel was off screen. What I did was kept the layout hidden and on screen, then used the animations to put it at correct location.

Comment: I don't think SlidingMenu allows from bottom; left, right only, I believe

Comment: @wkhatch is correct, a BOTTOM SlidingMenu throws the exception: "SlidingMenu mode must be LEFT, RIGHT, or LEFT_RIGHT" which is in-line with the documentation and contrary to this answer.

Answer (score 4):

My code to make animation slide up, slide down without XML

```
private static ObjectAnimator createBottomUpAnimation(View view,
        AnimatorListenerAdapter listener, float distance) {
    ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationY", -distance);
//        animator.setDuration(???)
    animator.removeAllListeners();
    if (listener != null) {
        animator.addListener(listener);
    }
    return animator;
}

public static ObjectAnimator createTopDownAnimation(View view, AnimatorListenerAdapter listener,
        float distance) {
    view.setTranslationY(-distance);
    ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationY", 0);
    animator.removeAllListeners();
    if (listener != null) {
        animator.addListener(listener);
    }
    return animator;
}
```

**Using**
For slide down

```
createTopDownAnimation(myYellowView, null, myYellowView.getHeight()).start();
```

For slide up

```
createBottomUpAnimation(myYellowView, null, myYellowView.getHeight()).start();
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try this below code, Its very short and simple.

**transalate_anim.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- Copyright (C) 2013 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="4000"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="-90%p" />

    <alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="4000"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.naveen.congratulations.MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/balloons" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_1);
        imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startBottomToTopAnimation(imageView1);
            }
        });

    }

    private void startBottomToTopAnimation(View view) {
        view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate_anim));
    }
}
```

[image: bottom_up_navigation of image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution as an extension of [https://stackoverflow.com/a/46644736/10249774]

Bottom panel is **pushing** main content upwards

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wuYA.jpg

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/my_button"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:onClick="onSlideViewButtonClick"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/main_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="main "
    android:textSize="70dp"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="main "
    android:textSize="70dp"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="main "
    android:textSize="70dp"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="main"
    android:textSize="70dp"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="main"
    android:textSize="70dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer_view"
    android:background="#a6e1aa"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="footer content"
        android:textSize="40dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="footer content"
        android:textSize="40dp" />
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button myButton;
private View footerView;
private View mainView;
private boolean isUp;
private int anim_duration = 700;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    footerView = findViewById(R.id.footer_view);
    mainView = findViewById(R.id.main_view);
    myButton = findViewById(R.id.my_button);

    // initialize as invisible (could also do in xml)
    footerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    myButton.setText("Slide up");
    isUp = false;
}
public void slideUp(View mainView , View footer_view){
    footer_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    TranslateAnimation animate_footer = new TranslateAnimation(
            0,                 // fromXDelta
            0,                 // toXDelta
            footer_view.getHeight(),  // fromYDelta
            0);                // toYDelta
    animate_footer.setDuration(anim_duration);
    animate_footer.setFillAfter(true);
    footer_view.startAnimation(animate_footer);

    mainView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    TranslateAnimation animate_main = new TranslateAnimation(
            0,                 // fromXDelta
            0,                 // toXDelta
            0,  // fromYDelta
            (0-footer_view.getHeight()));                // toYDelta
    animate_main.setDuration(anim_duration);
    animate_main.setFillAfter(true);
    mainView.startAnimation(animate_main);
}
public void slideDown(View mainView , View footer_view){
    TranslateAnimation animate_footer = new TranslateAnimation(
            0,                 // fromXDelta
            0,                 // toXDelta
            0,                 // fromYDelta
            footer_view.getHeight()); // toYDelta
    animate_footer.setDuration(anim_duration);
    animate_footer.setFillAfter(true);
    footer_view.startAnimation(animate_footer);


    TranslateAnimation animate_main = new TranslateAnimation(
            0,                 // fromXDelta
            0,                 // toXDelta
            (0-footer_view.getHeight()),  // fromYDelta
            0);                // toYDelta
    animate_main.setDuration(anim_duration);
    animate_main.setFillAfter(true);
    mainView.startAnimation(animate_main);
}

public void onSlideViewButtonClick(View view) {
    if (isUp) {
        slideDown(mainView , footerView);
        myButton.setText("Slide up");
    } else {
        slideUp(mainView , footerView);
        myButton.setText("Slide down");
    }
    isUp = !isUp;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define the mainscreen and the other screen that you want to scroll up as fragments. When the button on the mainscreen is pushed, the fragment would send a message to the activity which would then replace the mainscreen with the one that you want to scroll up and animate the replacement.

Comment: I just want the screen to pushed upwards by the hidden panel once it is on screen. I don't want to replace screen content / fragments. I managed to get it working with animations and layout tinkering.