# Android Layout Animations from bottom to top and top to bottom on ImageView click

Tags: android, android-animation

I have created a view in Android and I need to animate it from bottom to top and vice-versa. when I clicked on `ImageView` I need to animate the complete `RelativeLayout` from bottom to top and it is succeeded. But when I click again on `ImageView` and it is not moving down. Also, when I click on its original place, when I click the original position of the `ImageView` animation runs but the `RelativeLayout` moves down from the original position not a top to bottom.

This is my code:

```
ImageView iv_header;

RelativeLayout rl_footer;

boolean isBottom = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.rateus_layout);
    rl_footer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_footer);
    iv_header = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_up_arrow);

    iv_header.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (isBottom) {
                FooterAnimation();
                isBottom = false;
            } else {
                headerAnimation();
                isBottom = true;
            }

        }
    });
}

public void FooterAnimation() {
    Animation hide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.move);
    rl_footer.startAnimation(hide);
}

public void headerAnimation() {
    Animation hide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.footer);
    rl_footer.startAnimation(hide);
}
```

The animation file from bottom to top(Complete Relative Layout is moved from bottom to Top):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="1500"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:fromYDelta="0%p"
android:toYDelta="-85%p" />
```

The animation file from Top to bottom(i want again Relative Layout is moved from Top to Bottom):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="1500"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:fromYDelta="0%p"
android:toYDelta="84%p" />
```

The Xml File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rl_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/autograph_bg" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_footer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/down_manu_bar1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_new_file"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:onClick="onNewFileClick"
        android:src="@drawable/file_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_new_file"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/iv_new_file"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iv_new_file"
        android:text="New"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_insert"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv_new_file"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_new_file"
        android:src="@drawable/insert_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_insert"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/iv_insert"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iv_insert"
        android:text="Insert"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_up_arrow"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/up_arrow" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_down_arrow"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/down_arrow"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_save"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv_insert"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_up_arrow"
        android:src="@drawable/save" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/iv_save"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Save"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_settings"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv_save"
        android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_save"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_settings" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="260dp"
        android:text="Settings"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
  </RelativeLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Solved my problem and it's worked fine,please visit this link: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20374823/android-animate-my-relative-layout-from-bottom-to-top-and-top-to-bottom-using-tr

Comment: Try this short and simple answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46722909/2599596

Comment: Here is the correct answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23578059/make-activity-animate-from-top-to-bottom/23752530

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I have solved my issue and now my animation works fine :)
if anyone needed just copy my code and xml file and have a happy coding :)

My Activity MainActivity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

RelativeLayout rl_footer;
ImageView iv_header;
boolean isBottom = true;
Button btn1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    rl_footer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_footer);
    iv_header = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_up_arrow);
    iv_header.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            iv_header.setImageResource(R.drawable.down_arrow);
            iv_header.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 0); 
            rl_footer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.up_manu_bar);
            if (isBottom) {
                SlideToAbove();
                isBottom = false;
            } else {
                iv_header.setImageResource(R.drawable.up_arrow);
                iv_header.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 10);
                rl_footer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.down_manu_bar1);
                SlideToDown();
                isBottom = true;
            }

        }
    });

}

public void SlideToAbove() {
    Animation slide = null;
    slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -5.0f);

    slide.setDuration(400);
    slide.setFillAfter(true);
    slide.setFillEnabled(true);
    rl_footer.startAnimation(slide);

    slide.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            rl_footer.clearAnimation();

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    rl_footer.getWidth(), rl_footer.getHeight());
            // lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
            rl_footer.setLayoutParams(lp);

        }

    });

}

public void SlideToDown() {
    Animation slide = null;
    slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 5.2f);

    slide.setDuration(400);
    slide.setFillAfter(true);
    slide.setFillEnabled(true);
    rl_footer.startAnimation(slide);

    slide.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            rl_footer.clearAnimation();

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    rl_footer.getWidth(), rl_footer.getHeight());
            lp.setMargins(0, rl_footer.getWidth(), 0, 0);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
            rl_footer.setLayoutParams(lp);

        }

    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

 }
```

and my Xml activity_main:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/rl_main"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/autograph_bg" >

 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_footer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/down_manu_bar1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_new_file"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:onClick="onNewFileClick"
        android:src="@drawable/file_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_new_file"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/iv_new_file"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iv_new_file"
        android:text="New"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_insert"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv_new_file"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_new_file"
        android:src="@drawable/insert_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_insert"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/iv_insert"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iv_insert"
        android:text="Insert"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_up_arrow"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/up_arrow" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_down_arrow"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/down_arrow"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_save"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv_insert"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_up_arrow"
        android:src="@drawable/save" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/iv_save"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Save"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_settings"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv_save"
        android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_save"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_settings" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="260dp"
        android:text="Settings"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
 </RelativeLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

just create new android project and copy paste my code and have fun! :)
also remember in xml i have image view and his background images replace with yout own images thanks..

Comment: Hi Farhan Shah  can you provide `R.drawable.up_manu_bar` and `R.drawable.down_manu_bar1`

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged

Answer (score 36):

Try this :

Create **anim** folder inside your res folder and copy this four files :

slide_in_bottom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromYDelta="100%p"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
```

slide_out_bottom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromYDelta="0" 
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

slide_in_top.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:toYDelta="0%p"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

slide_out_top.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:toYDelta="100%p"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

When you click on image view call:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_bottom, R.anim.slide_out_bottom);
```

When you click on original place call:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_top, R.anim.slide_out_top);
```

Main Activity :

```
package com.example.animationtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button btn1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);


    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, test.class));

        }
    });


}
    }
```

activity_main.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button1" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

test.java :

```
package com.example.animationtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class test extends Activity {

Button btn1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right,
                    R.anim.slide_out_right);
            startActivity(new Intent(test.this, MainActivity.class));


        }
    });
}

    }
```

test.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button1" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i'd add your code but it's not working..can u please modify my code because i am near to achieve my target..my bottom to top animations works fine..and Relative Layout move up..but when again click its not moving down..and when i click on its original position it's animate and the complete relative layout move down from it's original position and i does't see my layout in my activity..when again i clicked on its original position the complete layout start the animation form it's original position and move up from bottom to   top...

Comment: Basically i simply want when i click on imageview my complete Relative Layout is move up from bottom to top..and when i click again on imageview it's move down from top to bottom..

Comment: Can you give me your email id,I have the sample working code or else i can edit my answer.

Comment: my email id is farhanshah_1987@yahoo.com

Comment: dear i checked ur code..basically you are oaverlaped the test activity into the mainactivity..can i send u my sample code to u at sid_5100@yahoo.com ??in my sample code u have got my exact point..

Comment: when activity open click the arrow image in the circle..it's move up..now when i again click that arrow image this time i want it move down but when i click nothing happen..dear have u got my point?

Comment: Your code is showing BufferOverflow exception.I am trying to solve that.

Comment: is there a way to use Animator instead?

Comment: very very helpfull...!

Answer (score 12):

create directory in /res/anim
and create bottom_to_original.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="1500"
        android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="1%" />
</set>
```

**JAVA:**

```
    LinearLayout ll = findViewById(R.id.ll);

    Animation animation;
    animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.sample_animation);
    ll .setAnimation(animation);
```

Answer (score 6):

Below Kotlin code will help

**Bottom to Top or Slide to Up**

```
private fun slideUp() {
    isMapInfoShown = true
    views!!.layoutMapInfo.visible()
    val animate = TranslateAnimation(
        0f,  // fromXDelta
        0f,  // toXDelta
        views!!.layoutMapInfo.height.toFloat(),  // fromYDelta
        0f  // toYDelta
    )

    animate.duration = 500
    animate.fillAfter = true
    views!!.layoutMapInfo.startAnimation(animate)
}
```

**Top to Bottom or Slide to Down**

```
private fun slideDown() {
    if (isMapInfoShown) {
        isMapInfoShown = false
        val animate = TranslateAnimation(
            0f,  // fromXDelta
            0f,  // toXDelta
            0f,  // fromYDelta
            views!!.layoutMapInfo.height.toFloat()  // toYDelta
        )

        animate.duration = 500
        animate.fillAfter = true
        views!!.layoutMapInfo.startAnimation(animate)
        views!!.layoutMapInfo.gone()
    }
}
```

**Kotlin Extensions for Visible and Gone**

```
fun View.visible() {
    this.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}


fun View.gone() {
    this.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved with very less lines of code with the latest apis added in the new Android releases. For example below is the code to slide from bottom to top.

```
public void slideFromBottomToTop() {
    ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationY", 100f, 0f);
    animation.setDuration(1000);
    animation.start();
}
```

For other animations reffer this link
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/animations/reposition-view