# Android: Activity Animation to top

Tags: android, xml, android-animation

I have written an xml that works well to move an activity from right to left on click. But now what exactly I want is to convert that xml in code that will move an activity from bottom to top on click.

Here is my xml for right to left

right1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

   <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0%p"
        android:duration="200" />
</set>
```

And here is another xml right2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

   <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="100%p"
        android:duration="200" />
</set>
```

And here I used this code for switching between activities

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);

startActivity(intent);
                    Activity1.this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right1, R.anim.right2);
```

Now I want it to change to bottom top move, that is to move activity from bottom to top. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

push_up_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
```

push_up_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="-100%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
```

For changing activity :

```
Intent nextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                nextactivity.class);
startActivity(nextActivity);
overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slide_up_in, R.anim.slide_up_out );
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this if you are looking for Top-Bottom and Bottom-Up animations :

[Android Animation Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323628/android-layout-animations-from-bottom-to-top-and-top-to-bottom-on-imageview-clic/20323729#20323729)

You can change the value of fromDelta and toDelta if you want from left-right and right-left animations.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For bottom to Top animation use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="800"
android:fromYDelta="100%p"
android:toYDelta="0%p" />
```

you can specify the duration that you want to implement in mili seconds.