# How to open activity from bottom to top in android

Tags: android

I want to start my activity from bottom to top just like the sliding effect, and i searched and even used all the possible codes but its not working so can anyone please help me out for this.
I even used below code:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up);
```

I have also using following xmls also:

slide-in-up.xml

```
<translate
    android:duration="5000"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p"
    android:toYDelta="0" />

<alpha
    android:duration="5000"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />
```

slide-out-up.xml

```
<translate
    android:duration="5000"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="-100%p" />

<alpha
    android:duration="5000"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.0" />
```

but then too its not working.

Comment: When you say it's not working, what is wrong ? Is there an error ? Maybe you need to do "getRessource().getAnimation(R.anim.slide_in_up)"

Comment: @Tsunaze It's not giving me error but animation what i want that's not going to place.(slide activity from bottom to UP).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
Animation animMove;
animMove = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                R.anim.move);
        animMove.setAnimationListener(this);
```

where your move.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

   <translate
        android:fromYDelta="50%p"
        android:toYDelta="0%p"
        android:duration="800" />
</set>
```

Here you have to change **fromYDelta** parameter as per your requirenment.

Comment: I have try this but could not found animMove.setAnimationListener(this); this is giveing me error.

Comment: Where you are using this code, i mean inside which method.

Comment: onButtonClickListener when I am trying to pass the activity using intent.

Comment: then use `animMove.setAnimationListener(yourActivityname.this);` instead of `animMove.setAnimationListener(this);`

Comment: Like if your activity name is MainActivity.java then pass `animMove.setAnimationListener(MainActivity.this);`

Comment: Change `android:fromYDelta="50%p"` percentage of this parameter as per your requirement.

Comment: but then use animMove.setAnimationListener(yourActivityname.this); instead of animMove.setAnimationListener(this); this is what i had used but its also not working

Comment: RelativeLayout relrewards = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relrewards);
  relrewards.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    /*overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_up,
      R.anim.slide_out_up);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MoreActivity.this,
      SignUpRewardMore.class);
    startActivity(intent);*/

    
     Animation animMove; animMove = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
     getApplicationContext(), R.anim.move);
      animMove.setAnimationListener(MoreActivity.this);
     
   }
  });

Answer (score 0):

Define an animation in res/anim/slide_in_up.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
```

and another at res/anim/slide_out_up.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="-100%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
```

Then apply these after to call startActivity:

```
Intent i2 = new Intent(main.this, test.class);
startActivity(i2);
overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up );
```

Comment: this is actual code that i am using but animation is not working. Can you please give an alternative for this.

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer below if you are looking for Top-Bottom and Bottom-Top animations :

[Android Animation Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323628/android-layout-animations-from-bottom-to-top-and-top-to-bottom-on-imageview-clic/20323729#20323729)

You can change the value of fromDelta and toDelta if you want from left-right and right-left animations.

Hope this helps.