# Android layout animation

Tags: android, android-animation

i have a button at the bottom of layout, on clicking on that button that button should be moved to top(with 48 DP margin from top).
How to do that please help.

Comment: Refer this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323628/android-layout-animations-from-bottom-to-top-and-top-to-bottom-on-imageview-clic

Comment: this is not working, i tried it before.

Answer (score 0):

place this move.xml in anim folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:fillAfter="true">

<translate
android:fromYDelta="0%p"
android:toYDelta="-80%p"
android:duration="800" />
</set>
```

and use for animate that button use this code

```
// Animation
final Animation move_anim =   AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.move);
```

and put this in to your onclick event

```
btn.startAnimation(move_anim)
```

Comment: how to give 48 dp margin in this 75% ?

Comment: no need of margin set in this animation .xml you can keep margin as it is from your main .xml if still you cant get it just feel free to ask.. :)