# How can i decrease image size when image is falling from top to bottom?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, zooming

How can i decrease image size when image is falling from top to bottom?

I have developed top to bottom process through below link

[Android Layout Animations from bottom to top and top to bottom on ImageView click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323628/android-layout-animations-from-bottom-to-top-and-top-to-bottom-on-imageview-clic)

But i am facing one problem.How can i decrease size of image when image is falling top to bottom?

Please let me share your idea or link and code.

Please see my requirement in below image.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can apply scale transformation to that view.

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setScale(valueX, valueY);
view.setTransform(matrix);
```

For imageView

```
imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved my question.I hope everyone will like it.

1.Create anim/zoom_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
android:fillAfter="true">
<scale
    android:duration="5000"
    android:fromXScale="100%"
    android:fromYScale="100%"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="50%"
    android:toYScale="50%" />

<translate
    android:duration="5000"
    android:fromYDelta="10%"
    android:toYDelta="50%" />
```

2.activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imgvw"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnZoomIn"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imgvw"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Zoom In" android:layout_marginLeft="100dp" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnZoomOut"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnZoomIn"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnZoomIn"
    android:text="Zoom Out" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

3.MainActivity.java file

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button btnzIn;
private Button btnzOut;
private ImageView img;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnzIn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnZoomIn);
    btnzOut = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnZoomOut);
    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgvw);
  /*  btnzIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

          //  img.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.zoom_in));
            img.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_down));
           // img.clearAnimation();
        }
    });*/
    btnzOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        //    img.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_up));
            img.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.zoom_out));

        }
    });
}
```