# scroll an image across the screen with button click

Tags: java, android

Could anyone offer any advice on how I can get an image to scroll smoothly from one side of the screen to another?

I am a java novice and I have followed some guides that do this in games using gdx, but this is just in a simple app and on one of the pages I want to click a button and then after clicking some text appears and the image slowly moves across the sky from one side to the other.

I have already done the code to make the text appear, but I can't figure out how to get the image to move. I know roughly I will need to give it an x and y position and then a new x and y position and possibly a timer with 3000 to give me 3 seconds but I don't know how to put this all together :(

So far I have for the onClick method for the button,

//when button clicked

```
public void imageMove(View view) {
textView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

I am now stuck on how to write the code to make the image move :(

Many thanks for any help

Danny

Answer (score 0):

This thread will help you man :

[Android Layout Animations from bottom to top and top to bottom on ImageView click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323628/android-layout-animations-from-bottom-to-top-and-top-to-bottom-on-imageview-clic)

When you are in your imageMove method triggered by the onClick from your button, you just have to animate your images. A full example is given in the thread above. Hope this help you !