# What is the alternative of SlidingDrawer which is deprecated? For sliding up from bottom

Tags: android, slidingmenu, slidingdrawer

Hey I need some sliding menu from bottom of screen. And I saw that the SlidingDrawer is deprecated.

So what is the alternative to SlidingDrawer which I can use for sliding up from bottom.

I know there is the NavigationDrawer, but I think that's only useable for sliding from left to right and reverse, or?

Comment: See this link may help   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232372/slide-a-layout-up-from-bottom-of-screen

Comment: You can look at https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/SlidingDrawer, which mekes it possible for you to slide from any side.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

check out this library

https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

it is from the [umano app](http://umanoapp.com), that has released some code.

> The 2.2 version of the Umano Android app features a sexy sliding up
>   draggable panel for the currently playing article. This type of a
>   panel is a common pattern also used in the Google Music app and the
>   Rdio app. This is an open source implementation of this component that
>   you are free to take advantage of in your apps. Umano Team <3 Open
>   Source.

Comment: Oh yeah, of course, SlidingDrawer was too much straightforward and its API was clear and predictable. I would have wiped it away too. Just like TabHost. Nice hit again Google. What next? ListView?

Comment: @TechNyquist Ha! You called it. Bet you weren't surprised when you saw Recyclerview pop up

Answer (score 2):

Use this :-
https://github.com/6wunderkinder/android-sliding-layer-lib

You can slide from any direction using this project

Answer (score 0):

This blog is pretty thorough if you want to make your own version:

http://darkgoddess.org/wonderland/2013/03/09/slidingdrawer-is-dead-long-live-slidingdrawer/