# How to set "toYDelta" attribute in java code?

Tags: android, xml, android-animation

I've got many `textView`s and below each of them, a `tableLayout` which has `visibility.GONE` at the very beginning . 
I am trying to expand the `tableLayout` which is belong to a `textView` when the `textView` is clicked . I've assigned `alpha` animation to `tableLayout`s and `translate` animation to those `textView`s are below the clicked one .

since the size of my `tableLayout` are different  I have to set `toYDelta` and `fromYDelta`
separately in a new animation for clicking every `textView` !!
and I think it is totally hard code !!!

My question is : Is there any method I can use it to modify `toYDelta` in may code programmatically ?

Or can anyone help me other way to do that please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several alternatives for doing this. The simplest one is probably to use a `ViewPropertyAnimator`, e.g.

```
view.animate().translationY(value);
```

To get the current value (for example if you want to update it with a fixed offset) you can use [`view.getTranslationY()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTranslationY%28%29).

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html