# Android: Sliding menu from the bottom

Tags: android, menu, contextmenu, navigation-drawer, slidingmenu

I want in my app create sliding menu which scroll from the bottom to the top. I have a button on the bottom of Activity and when user click on the button, then the menu should shown. When user click on the button again, then the menu should disappear. User should also can swipe up and down to show or disappear the menu.

The menu can look like in this app [Any.Do](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anydo)

Look at the screenshots below. Do you know how to do this? Do you have some tips?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Be aware that it goes against Android design guidelines, because user can miss your button and hit home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is have a view which animates up and down depending on it's state.

In this view you could house a fragment which would be the menu.

Comment: My solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232372/slide-a-layout-up-from-bottom-of-screen