# List appearing from bottom like, "Twitter Share"

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to Display a list of Modules in my android app.
Same as twitter share list, which pops up from the bottom side.
Half list is displays first and then after swiping again full list is displayed.
Can some one give me an idea?!

Thank You.

[image]

Comment: What is "Twitter Share"? Can you post an image?

Comment: Agreed. Without a screen shot or a concept image it's very hard to understand what you're asking.

Comment: did you look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232372/slide-a-layout-up-from-bottom-of-screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey I found the library which I was looking for,

https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet