# how to minimize and maximize a page in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, google-music

I've two android pages say for example media library and media player... After clicking a song in media library my song is played in media player, Now I want to minimize my media player and browse library how can I do that...

Just like google music ...
see the pictures below...

You'll find media player below docked and when you click that it slides up the media player and if you slide down media player is docked... how to achieve this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is duplicate question of ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765938/show-and-hide-a-view-with-a-slide-up-down-animation...

Comment: Check this out...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232372/slide-a-layout-up-from-bottom-of-screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to this example ->>https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel i hope u get ur sol

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion are two different activitys. You have to launch an intent to start the second activity.

More info here: http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/principles.html#

Comment: I'm asking for sliding operation bro... They can be activities or fragments what so ever...

Comment: Check this url [http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/principles.html#](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/principles.html#)