# Android How to make sliding menu?

Tags: java, android

Currently I'm trying to insert a drop-down kind of sliding menu (not sure how it's called). The idea is that user touches the arrow or any area of the menu and drag upwards in order to open the menu. But I have no idea how or where can I find tutorial for this.

[image]

Comment: or check this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232372/slide-a-layout-up-from-bottom-of-screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232372/slide-a-layout-up-from-bottom-of-screen)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this code posted in github: https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel.

You can design your own view in sliding menu.

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppaneldemo.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="My Content"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center|top"
        android:text="Another Content"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</com.sothree.slidinguppaneldemo.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

Comment: Hope library meet your requirements

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way would be using a library like https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

But since google released [CoordinatorLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html) and [Behavior](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.Behavior.html) I would recommend you to take a look at that, although it's kinda new and much harder to do.