# how can we slide a hidden layout from the bottom of screen to middle screen in android?

Tags: android, android-sliding

I am new to android i want to design a layout for my that is slide a hidden layout from the bottom of screen to middle screen in android.How can i achieve it please helpme out.Bellow is my sample screen

[image]

Comment: checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232372/slide-a-layout-up-from-bottom-of-screen

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library.
[Bottom Sheet](https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet)