# how to implement a bottom slide in popup window

Tags: android, popupwindow

Does anyone know how to implement a popup window as shown below, it slides in from the bottom, and supports a custom UI with abundant options. Any ideas about what the control is and how do we implement it?

[image]

Comment: Check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232372/slide-a-layout-up-from-bottom-of-screen), it may help you

Comment: Use this library https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet

Comment: @AnoopKanyan Why not create a answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To present a set of actions/menu which slides up from the bottom edge of the screen you can use this [library](https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet)

Comment: Yeah, this one looks nice and https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet is another good choice.