# Sliding down activity - Android Material Design App

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-transitions, androiddesignsupport

I've been to make this effect in Android. I've achieved to make a Share Element Intent succesfully but don't have a clue on how to get back to the previous activity by sliding down the second one.

The example of what I'd like to do is this: https://github.com/klinker41/android-slidingactivity/blob/master/preview.gif (But implemented with native resources)

Thank you.

Comment: show us the code so we can find the issue...

Comment: show us the code you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

I think you're searching for "BottomSheet",
Please Refer below link
 [This is for custom create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232372/slide-a-layout-up-from-bottom-of-screen)
and
[Material guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-sheets.html)
and
[Create Bottom Sheet from This link](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-use-bottom-sheets-with-the-design-support-library--cms-26031)