# android custom floating window

Tags: android, window, floating

> I have to make custom (I can set my layout.xml) floating window where
>   I can control Xco and Yco.

With Toast (in timer) I can achieve this but I have to avoid unnecessary timer.

I come across some library say, **SuperToolTip** (we can't control X and Y; rather we placed against some drawable) **StandOut** (here we can control Xco and Yco but it uses Services for just a simple thing)

Please help me.

**EDITED**

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);

Window window = dialog.getWindow();
WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();
wlp.x = 0;      
wlp.y = 200;
wlp.width = 800;
wlp.height= 400;
window.setAttributes(wlp);

dialog.setTitle(null);
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_audio_recording_hint, null);

dialog.setContentView(view);
dialog.setCancelable(false);

ImageButton imgBtnCloseDialog = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imgBtnCloseDialog);
imgBtnCloseDialog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }


});


ImageButton imgBtnAudio = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnAudio);
imgBtnAudio.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: How about `Dialog`? To change dialog position: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467026/change-dialog-position-on-the-screen

Comment: @Wenhui, thanks for your comment! Dialog assist me for what I am looking for...

Comment: Just an advice, don't use px, use density pixel instead. Your window position and sizes are pixel, which will not scale well a cross different device density.

Comment: @Wenhui, thanks for really valuable suggestion. I always keep in mind:)

Answer (score 1):

Use this Code android.widget.PopupWindow can be used to display an arbitrary view. The popup windows is a floating container that appears on top of the current activity.

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical" 
      android:background="@android:color/background_light">
      <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">
        >
      <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_margin="20dp">
      <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="It's a PopupWindow" />
      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
      <Button
          android:id="@+id/dismiss"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Dismiss" />
     </LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
```