# Android - DialogFragment, how to align with Activity's edge?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I am trying a very simple app where I'd like to display a `DialogFragment`. However I would like to align the `DialogFragment`'s right margin with the `Activity`'s right edge. I used layout gravity to align the Dialog's window to the right and top:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
        getDialog().getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP);
        return view;
    }

}
```

However there is 'gap' between the `DialogFragment`'s right edge and the `Activity`'s right by default. I've tried a few SO posts but none seem to work for me:

[Changing position of the Dialog on screen android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467026/changing-position-of-the-dialog-on-screen-android)

[Show AlertDialog in any position of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469005/show-alertdialog-in-any-position-of-the-screen)

I am trying to anchor my dialog to a particular coordinate pair but I am not successful with this approach. What I'd like to do is simply align the dialog's right margin with the `Activity`'s right edge.

Here is an image of my issue. Any direction or a solution would be most appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Maybe look into this: http://keepsafe.github.io/2014/11/19/building-a-custom-overflow-menu.html

Answer (score 1):

Unbelievable problem at first. First, the dialog is indeed aligned to the top right corner of the window. The reason it appears with an offset is because of a shadow around it (note that the width of the shadow various between pre-lollipop devices and devices running lollipop and above, similar to the way a dialog ui varies between Android versions).

This is very evident when the background of the `DialogFragment` is made transparent using this line in `onCreateView(..)`:

```
getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

An option would be to apply your own shadow to the DialogFragment's window after setting the background colour to transparent.