# How to position dialog to the bottom

Tags: android, dialog, kotlin, gravity

I am trying to set the dialog to the bottom but couldn't able to do that. 
It showing the top of the page.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="370dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardElevation="1dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">


            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView14"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorSecondaryBackground"
                android:fontFamily="@font/gotham_medium_regular"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="Send Promotions"
                android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/promotionDataLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/two_margin"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView14">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/promotionList"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineEnd"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineStart"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

                    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                        android:id="@+id/guidelineStart"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.08" />

                    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                        android:id="@+id/guidelineEnd"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.92" />


                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>          
                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </ScrollView>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabDone"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:src="@drawable/red_plus"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/cv1"
        app:elevation="1dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center|bottom" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I am creating the dialog class like that:

```
class PromotionDialog:Dialog{

   var mContext:Context?=null
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {}

    constructor(context: Context, themeResId: Int) : super(context, themeResId) {
        mContext=context
    }

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.promotion_layout)// use your layout in place of this.

        window.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

    }

   }
```

Solution Tried:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9467151/1640009
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9467151/1640009

I can't use bottomsheetdialog due to design constraint.

EDIT: 
I am calling the dialog like this

```
val promotionDialog= PromotionDialog(this@DashboardActivity, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_NoActionBar_Fullscreen)
    promotionDialog.show()
```

EDIT 2:

As @RAJA suggested, It was because of the FUll screen theme.

So now I have change the theme to :

```
 <style name="ThemeDialog" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">100%</item>
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">100%</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>

    </style>
```

But still there are some margin in the bottom

Comment: I tried this, Is working.. see my updated post

Comment: Which theme you are using in use application manifest file

Comment: Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar @Raja. It is done. It was because of fixed height. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try like this :

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.promotion_layout)// use your layout in place of this.

        window.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        val windowlp = window.attributes

        windowlp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM
        window.attributes = windowlp

    }
```

Access your dialog view in your Activity

```
PromotionDialog(this).show();
```

Comment: I have updated the question with how I am calling the dialog. Since I need make it full screen width that why I am using the full screen theme

Comment: Ohh I think because of full screen theme it is getting the full page, not the required section. That's why gravity property not working.

Comment: Yes remove your theme or give any other theme

Comment: Hey, I have remove that theme but still I have some padding at the bottom. Please check my edited question