# how to define the position of a alert dialog in view

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show AlertDialog in any position of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469005/show-alertdialog-in-any-position-of-the-screen)

I making an application in which I display an `alert dialog`.I want use a `custom layout` for my alert dialog.How can I set its position according to my need in a `view/layout`.

My code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbarmain,null);
view.setMinimumWidth(200);
view.setMinimumHeight(400);

AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alertDialog.setView(view);
alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469005/show-alertdialog-in-any-position-of-the-screen) question and the accepted answer.

Comment: the compiler is showing problwm in getWindow() and requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Comment: Post your code where you are calling this I hope in `onCreate()` of your activity.

Comment: Are you calling getWindow() before show()?

Comment: Please tell me how to remove this problem.Even i have imported  android.view.Window;
android.view.WindowManager;

Comment: yes i am calling it before show()

Comment: You should call `getWindow()` before `setContentView()`.This will fix your problem.

Comment: The method requestWindowFeature(int) is undefined for the type AlertDialog.Builder

Comment: The method getWindow() is undefined for the type AlertDialog.Builder this is the problem with getWindow()

Comment: Please tell me the solution or any alternate way to solve this problem

Comment: what you want to show in your dialog??

Comment: @AkashG please help me sir if you can

Comment: How many buttons are there in linear layout and whats there orientation??

Answer (score 0):

Create an activity with your required layout and specify theme as dialog in manifest.

This is a sample : You need to change it according to your req

```
public class EditPropertyActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    // @Override
    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        setTitle("");
        TextView propName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_propName);          

        propName.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("prop_label"));

        final EditText ed_propValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_propValue);
        ed_propValue.setText(value);
        if (tagName.equals("timeout")) {
            ed_propValue.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        }
        Button btn_save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
        btn_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        //onclick
        }
    }
```

In manifest:

```
        <activity
            android:name="EditPropertyActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
        </activity>
```

Layout dialog.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_propName"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ed_propValue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_save"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/lbl_btn_save" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort ma'am but this is not the solution of my problem. i am getting the same problem again and again

Comment: Ok then thanks for your effort

Answer (score 0):

to add custom layout in alert dialog,you have to inflate layout in it:

testxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="test" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="test" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="test" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If you want to inflate this xml in alert dialog than:

```
                AlertDialog.Builder builder=new Builder(YourActivityName.this);
                LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
                View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.testxml, null);
                builder.setView(view);
                builder.setTitle("New Project");
                builder.setMessage("knknknknknmknknknk");
                builder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
                builder.create();
                builder.show();
```

Comment: i have just taken linear layout having 3 buttons having orientation vertical same you can add as many buttons to it and can change the orientation as per your requirements.i implemented this to clear your problem and set this layout as a view in AlertDialog.