# Place Dialog where user touches the screen

Tags: java, android, dialog, touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show AlertDialog in any position of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469005/show-alertdialog-in-any-position-of-the-screen)

As you know Default `Dialog` has got `Gravity` properties like `Right`, `Top` etc. but is it possible to place Dialog where user touches screen other than default gravity properties?

Using tapped x and y coordinates from onTouch(...) method or something like that, is it possible?

Say for example, I touched (50, 50) x and y coordinates on screen, may not be exactly at that same position but anywhere near to that touched point.

Comment: Duplicate. BTW wow this was posted, answered, reposted answered, upvoted and accepted so fast..

Comment: oops... was bit hurry... sorry :(

Answer (score 3):

Get the co-ordinates of the action from an event (from say onTouchListener) and then use the dialog's layout params to set the position

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = myDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
params.x = 300;
params.y = 300;
myDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```