# Android - Is it possible to change the gravity of a custom dialog?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

The image below is essentially what I want to achieve, this comes straight out of eclipse as my dialog_layout.xml

I want to inflate a custom dialog and have it on the right of screen to serve as a menu. Everytime, I try to show this `DialogFragment`, the layout below centres itself to the centre of the screen. (The code for the `onCreateDialog()` of the `DialogFragment1 is below the image.

Is there any way to achieve this? Do I have to create an Activity using a dialog theme?

[image: Desired dialog]

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // Create a new Dialog using the AlertDialog Builder
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    View background = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);

    builder.setView(background);        

    return builder.create();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469005/show-alertdialog-in-any-position-of-the-screen

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? If so, please comment.

Comment: I did, there were quite a few issues in the end. Your link helped me sort out the gravity though, cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Success!

I used a DialogFragment to produce a custom menu dialog in the top right of the screen.

[image]

Reasoning:

- Needed big buttons therefore standard menu was too small.
- Standard menu is a hassle to inflate from a custom menu button.
- I wanted a fairly slim dialog in the top right, same position as the users thumb when pressing the         menu button. This is the same logic as most menus.

Problems faced:

- Unwanted black border around my dialog   ||   **Solution:** dialog.setView(dialogLayout, 0, 0, 0, 0);
- Dialog was always centred   ||   **Solution:** Changed the WindowParams.
- Dialog occupied the majority of the screen even though the XML design can be seen at the very start    ||    **Solution:** Apply a custom transparent windowBackground theme

Code:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // Create a new Dialog and apply a transparent window background style
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.dialog_theme);                 
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

    // Create the custom dialog layout and set view with initial spacing parameters to prevent black background
    View dialogLayout = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment_menu, null);
    dialog.setView(dialogLayout, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    // Change the standard gravity of the dialog to Top | Right.
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wlmp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();       
    wlmp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT;

    return dialog;
}
```

The code for my style is simply:

```
<style name="dialog_theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```