# Activity over navdrawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am trying to design a screen that must be rendered above anything (kind of like an alert, but it can't be an alert). As I am very new to Android development my only worry is that this window must be put above even the navdrawer. Can this be done?

Thanks

[EDIT]
It's like that:
http://flic.kr/p/k3XRzv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why do you not want to use the alertbuilder? - simple, easy to use and flexible?

Comment: Is it flexible enough to do something like that image i've loaded? 
Thanks

Comment: AndreyRothEhrenberg you also could use a navigation drawer for the "whatever_song" feature, or an alerdialog builder with something like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469005/show-alertdialog-in-any-position-of-the-screen

.. but the ux will be better with the navdrawer ;-)

Comment: I used an alerdialog builder. Thanks a lot!