# How to create custom dropdown/popup view with buttons textviews etc in android

Tags: android, layout, drop-down-menu, menu, popupwindow

I ned to create a custom pop in which i can show any layout containing buttons, textviews, edittexts and any other control but the view has to appear like dropdown/popup. An example of view I want to create is shown in the image below. I know about popup menus, spinners, lists ets but I don't[image] think that these things will help me to create the view shown in the Image

Comment: see [quick action grid menu in android](http://mayanklangalia.blogspot.in/2014/04/how-to-create-quick-action-grid-menu-in.html) probably help

Comment: You have to use animations.Its possible in animation concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Custom Dialogs, with a background image like in the provided image.

```
 Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
 dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
```

You can get more from [this](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/) link

Comment: Dialog can not give me the view like above like when I have to show them on particular locations . See the image I have given

Comment: Hope this helps.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469005/show-alertdialog-in-any-position-of-the-screen