# show alertdialog and not cover the actionbar

Tags: android

I'm new in android and I'm trying to use alertdialog but it always covers the actionbar.

How can I do something like dropdown menu as shown in the picture ?

I[image]

Comment: for drop down you should use spinner instead of alert dialog

Comment: but the spinner show vertical line by line

Comment: you can inflate your custom layout with it I think this kind of layout can be done too

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();

wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
 wmlp.x = 100;   //x position
 wmlp.y = 100;   //y position

 dialog.show();
```

source https://stackoverflow.com/a/6050911/1320616

Comment: The alert dialog backgroud still cover the the actionBar.

Comment: Try using `wmlp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM` instead of `wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP`